# Router 1 doesn't learn the routes

Tags: router, gns3

[image]

Hello,

I've activated rip on all 3 routers with version 2 but R1 fails to ping R3 and vice versa. I've configured the vlans of the switches with their ips. I've been try a while now to get this fixed.

```
**Router 1 : show ip protocols**
Routing Protocol is "rip"
  Outgoing update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Incoming update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Sending updates every 30 seconds, next due in 19 seconds
  Invalid after 180 seconds, hold down 180, flushed after 240
  Redistributing: rip
  Default version control: send version 2, receive version 2
    Interface             Send  Recv  Triggered RIP  Key-chain
    FastEthernet0/0       2     2
  Automatic network summarization is not in effect
  Maximum path: 4
  Routing for Networks:
    10.0.0.0
  Routing Information Sources:
    Gateway         Distance      Last Update
  Distance: (default is 120)

**Router 2:show ip protocols**
Routing Protocol is "rip"
  Outgoing update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Incoming update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Sending updates every 30 seconds, next due in 14 seconds
  Invalid after 180 seconds, hold down 180, flushed after 240
  Redistributing: rip
  Default version control: send version 2, receive version 2
    Interface             Send  Recv  Triggered RIP  Key-chain
    FastEthernet0/0       2     2
    Serial1/0             2     2
  Automatic network summarization is not in effect
  Maximum path: 4
  Routing for Networks:
    10.0.0.0
  Routing Information Sources:
    Gateway         Distance      Last Update
    10.15.1.14           120      00:00:22
  Distance: (default is 120)

**Router 3:show ip protocols**
Routing Protocol is "rip"
  Outgoing update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Incoming update filter list for all interfaces is not set
  Sending updates every 30 seconds, next due in 10 seconds
  Invalid after 180 seconds, hold down 180, flushed after 240
  Redistributing: rip
  Default version control: send version 2, receive version 2
    Interface             Send  Recv  Triggered RIP  Key-chain
    FastEthernet0/0       2     2
    Serial1/0             2     2
  Automatic network summarization is not in effect
  Maximum path: 4
  Routing for Networks:
    10.0.0.0
  Routing Information Sources:
    Gateway         Distance      Last Update
    10.15.1.13           120      00:00:09
  Distance: (default is 120)

**RIP config on all 3 routers:**
router rip
 version 2
 network 10.0.0.0
 no auto-summary

**R1#show ip route**
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/24 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       10.24.0.0 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C    192.168.137.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1


**R2#show ip route**
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.15.1.12/30 is directly connected, Serial1/0
C       10.24.0.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
R       10.23.1.0/24 [120/1] via 10.15.1.14, 00:00:15, Serial1/0


R3#show ip route
Codes: C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 3 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.15.1.12/30 is directly connected, Serial1/0
R       10.24.0.0/24 [120/1] via 10.15.1.13, 00:00:00, Serial1/0
C       10.23.1.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
```

I'm not able to figure where the problem lies. Please help

EDIT: (Output from Comments)

```
R1#show run int fa 0/0 
Building configuration... 
Current configuration : 93 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/0 
 ip address 10.24.0.1 255.255.255.0 
 speed 100
 full-duplex 

end 

R1#show run int fa 0/1
Building configuration...
Current configuration : 74 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/1 
 ip address dhcp 
 speed 100 
 full-duplex

end

R1#ping 10.15.1.13 (ip of f0/1 of R2) 
Type escape sequence to abort. 
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.15.1.13, timeout is 2 seconds: 
..... 
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5) 

R1#ping 10.24.0.2 (ip of f0/0 of R1)
Type escape sequence to abort. 
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.24.0.2, timeout is 2 seconds: 
!!!!! 
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 76/84/92 ms
```

Comment: R1 cant seem to talk to R2.  Can you ping from R1 to R2?  If not, start there. I'm suspicious of the switch configurations.

Comment: fa0/0 (10.24.0.1) on r1 is not pinging fa0/1 (10.15.1.13) on r2. I'm not sure how to get that to work.

Comment: Can you ping R2 f0/0 from R1 f0/0?

Comment: R1#ping 10.15.1.13       (ip of f0/1 of R2)

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.15.1.13, timeout is 2 seconds:
.....
Success rate is 0 percent (0/5)
R1#ping 10.24.0.2           (ip of f0/0 of R1)

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.24.0.2, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 76/84/92 ms

Comment: That's not what I asked. Can you ping f0/0 of R2?

Comment: i ain't gonna spend more than 30 sec on this but will help you. 1. Enable whatever routing protocol you want on the routers. The `network` command usually tells the routing protocol daemon know which addresses to include/advertise. Sometimes you need to enable the routing protocol per interface, sometimes not. If you having any issues, debug out and/or debug in and read the logs. It ain't that difficult. It ain't rocket science.

Comment: R1 and R2 do not recognize each other.  Please post the configs of both routers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Interface F0/0 and F0/1 on R1 are misconfigured.**

**R1** interface F0/0 is configured for `192.168.137.0/24` instead of `10.24.0.0/24`.  **R1** interface F0/1 is configured for `10.24.0.0/24` instead of `192.168.137.0/24`.  I recommend either "swapping" your cables or re-IP addressing your interfaces.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. As far as I can see, the interfaces and their IPs are configured right.

Comment: Run the following commands on R1: `show run int fa 0/0` and `show run int fa 0/1`.  Please post the output into your original question.  I highly suspect that the output of fa 0/0 will show an address of 192.168.137.0/24 and fa 0/1 will show a 10.24.0.0/24 address.  According to your diagram, your interface configurations are "flipped".

Comment: R1#show run int fa 0/0
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 93 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 10.24.0.1 255.255.255.0
 speed 100
 full-duplex
end

R1#show run int fa 0/1
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 74 bytes
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address dhcp
 speed 100
 full-duplex
end

Comment: Looks like **R1** interfaces are configured as per your diagram.  Can you post the same for **R2**?  there is still a chance that **R2** fa 0/0 is misconfigured.